# jquery star rating get value radio hidden

Tags: jquery

i use star rating http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/

i don't understand how to get the value of the hidden radio checked by the user after submit the form

here the code:

```
         <div class="line mrgT mrgB" id="starVin">
            <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star" value="1" />
            <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star" value="2" />
            <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star" value="3" />
            <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star" value="4" />
            <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star" value="5" />
        </div>
```

i try this

```
alert( $('#formComent .star1:checked').val() );
```

doesn't work...

Comment: How are you using this? Is your `alert` inside an `on('click', ...)` handler? Please provide more JavaScript code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use `[name="star1"]` in your selector since it is the name, or `.star` as it is the class, not `star1`. You may have an ID on your form of `formComment`, but since it isn't included in your example use `starVin` in the selector as well:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
alert( jQuery('#starVin input[name="star1"]:checked').val() );
```

or

```
alert( jQuery('#starVin .star:checked').val() );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tayNH/

If you want to test for `checked` you can use the `is()` method:

```
$('#starVin input[name="star1"]').each(function(){ alert($(this).is(':checked')); });
```

Comment: He has a class. I can see it right there in the HTML. But he's probably assigning it to several sets of inputs; impossible to know from this sample.

Comment: and doesn't work because all the input were hidden after execution of javascript it result: <input class="star star-rating-applied" type="radio" value="1" name="star1" style="display: none;">
<input class="star star-rating-applied" type="radio" value="2" name="star1" style="display: none;">
<input class="star star-rating-applied" type="radio" value="3" name="star1" style="display: none;">
<input class="star star-rating-applied" type="radio" value="4" name="star1" style="display: none;">
<input class="star star-rating-applied" type="radio" value="5" name="star1" style="display: none;">

Comment: i got error: TypeError: $("#starVin .star:checked") is null in the console

Comment: Are you sure you are loading the jQuery library?

Comment: yes, 1.4.1.min i use on the same page others jquery script   the alert is insie a javascript function call by a onclick on a link

Comment: then you likely have a conflict with another plugin, try using `noConflict()` - http://jsfiddle.net/tayNH/2/

Comment: jQuery.noConflict();

function AddComment(e, f) {

  ...
    
//alert( $('input[name=star1]:checked', '#formComent').val() );

alert( $('#starVin .star:checked').val() );

...
}

Comment: Use `jQuery` not `$` - this might be getting out of the realm of the original question though :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your markup, I think you want `$('#starVin input[name="star1"].star:checked').val()` (change id of container div from '#formComent' to '#starVin', add name specificity '[name="star1"]' and move ':checked' filter into selector, *then* get the value.

[See my jsfiddle for a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/qH9Je/).

Answer (score 0):

if have rating star, as a radio button, to get the value of that rating star I have written the following code. and its work fine for me.
this is my html and jquery code.

```
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" class="get_value" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="get_value" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="get_value" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="get_value"id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="get_value" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="get_value" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="get_value" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="get_value" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="get_value" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="get_value" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>

<script>
var star_rating = 0;
$(".get_value").click(function () {
    if($(this).prop("checked")) {
        star_rating = $(this).val();
        console.log(star_rating);
    }
});
</script>
```